# problem in updating an index of state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.state = {foo : [{x:20,y:40},{x:55,y:10},{x:8,y:90},{x:0,y:150}]};//state
this.state.foo[2].x = 80;//change state
```

I need to update index 2 of foo in x property. but with setState. how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following, which would avoid the need for a third-party library while also maintaining immutability in your state update:

```
// Clone the foo list from state
const foo = this.state.foo.map(item => ({ ...item }));

// Update element in cloned list
foo[2].x = 80;

// Update state with cloned list
this.setState({ foo });
```

Comment: Nice, but you need to wrap `{...item}` in parentheses.